# How to print a particular constraint in pulp for large problems

Tags: printing, constraints, out-of-memory, pulp

I am running a OR problem in Pulp with 600*159 decision variables and large set of constraints . every time if i add new constraint to problem to check the correctness of constraint, i put print(model) . my program not able to display due to high memory to show in console. so i use 'writelp' to download file and verify which is cumbersome. **can someone tell how to print only the constraint ,i need to see in console or any other option available.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I want to do something like this, it's easy to just store the constraint to a temporary variable, print that, and then add it to the problem:

```py
>>> x = pl.LpVariable(f"x", lowBound=0, upBound=None)
>>> constraint = x <= 3
>>> print(constraint)
x <= 3

>>> prob += constraint
```

A constraint is an instance of `pulp.LpConstraint`, which can be printed, since it has `__str__()` and `__repr__()` methods. In other words, it's just a python object.